# What is the best Django web portal framework?

Tags: python, django, content-management-system

Currently I'm looking for a cms based on Django to build a web portal. Any recommendations?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`django-cms`](http://www.django-cms.org/en/). Its an Open source enterprise content management system based on the django framework.

As per [Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ContentManagementSystems),

> It provides a full cms stack with the power of a webframework under
>   it. Easily extendable.

For some `django-cms` tutorials, go through this [link](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/introduction/index.html).

[`Mezzanine`](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/) is another such option.

As per their website:

> Mezzanine resembles tools such as Wordpress that provide an intuitive
>   interface for managing pages, blog posts, form data, store products,
>   and other types of content.